# Deleting rows that do not match first column criteria

Tags: excel

I have  the following table:

```
Date        Value
-------------------
1/2/1970    100
1/5/1970     99.99
1/6/1970    100.37
1/7/1970    100.74
1/8/1970    101.26
1/9/1970    100.74
1/12/1970   100.79
1/13/1970   101.27
1/14/1970   101.95
1/15/1970   101.97
1/16/1970   101.76
1/19/1970   102.21
1/20/1970   102.70
1/21/1970   102.00
1/22/1970   101.46
1/23/1970   101.49
1/26/1970   100.97
1/27/1970   101.45
1/28/1970   101.70
1/29/1970   102.08
1/30/1970   102.19
2/2/1970    102.02
2/3/1970    101.85
2/4/1970    101.69
2/5/1970    101.69
2/6/1970    101.66
2/9/1970    102.64
```

I need to delete all the rows where the date is not the second day of the month, I devised the following conditional but I'm not sure how to use it:

`=IF(A2<>EOMONTH(A2-1,2), B2)`

However, when I apply that formula to column C, it simply does not work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: if you want to test _date is not the second day of the month_, surely you mean `Day(A2) <> 2` ?

Comment: add `=IF(DAY(A2)=2,0,1)` to column C (fill down for all data) filter where = 0 highlight all rows containing data. Right click delete then remove filter.  remaining rows will only be all but 2nd day.

Comment: I tried that, however when I apply that to column C the output is all 1/0/1900 or 1/1/1900

Comment: @Muffinman Then change the format of that column to "General", It is set as short date and why you get that output.

Answer (score 2):

Running this short macro *(uses neilsen's test)*:

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, d As Date
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        d = Cells(i, 1).Value
        If Day(d) <> 2 Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Manually, you could use AutoFilter to achieve the same result.

Comment: What's "neilsen's test"?

Comment: The test Chris Neilsen mentions in the first comment of this question